# Add serial number for each id based on dates

Tags: case, serial-number, dense-rank

I have a dataset like shown below (except the Ser_NO, this is the field i want to create).

```
+--------+------------+--------+
| CaseID | Order_Date | Ser_No |
+--------+------------+--------+
|   44   | 22-01-2018 |   1    |
+--------+------------+--------+
|   44   | 24-02-2018 |   3    |
+--------+------------+--------+
|   44   | 12-02-2018 |   2    |
+--------+------------+--------+
|   100  | 24-01-2018 |   1    |
+--------+------------+--------+
|   100  | 26-01-2018 |   2    |
+--------+------------+--------+
|   100  | 27-01-2018 |   3    |
+--------+------------+--------+
```

How can i achieve a serial number for each CaseId based on my dates. So the first date in a specific CaseID gets number 1, the second date in this CaseID gets number 2 and so on.
I'm working with T-SQL btw,

I've tried a few things:

CASE
WHEN COUNT(CaseID) > 1
THEN ORDER BY (Order_Date) 
AND Ser_no +1 
END

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: CASE
WHEN COUNT(CaseID) > 1
THEN  Ser_NO + 1 ORDER BY Order_DATE
END

Something like this, I also was thinking about the partition function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, although I don't understand what you did, it gives you what you wanted. The serial number is assigned by date order. The problem I can see is that the result shows you the rows in the wrong order (1, 3, 2 instead of 1, 2, 3).

To sort that order you can try this:

```
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY caseid ORDER BY caseid, order_date) AS ser_no
FROM [Table]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply,
Sorry for the misunderstanding, because the ser_no is not yet in my table. That is the field a want to calculate.

I finished it myself this morning, but it looks almost the same like your measure:

RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CaseID ORDER BY CaseID, Order_Date ASC